# Locks on postgres transactions

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am load testing my node.js application. At some point I reach state where requests are pending and my best guess it's because of a locked transaction. This is the last log statement:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
```

And in `pg_lock` I've got 4 rows with the above query which are `GRANTED = true`, with `mode` `ExclusiveLock`.

Where should I start looking for a bug? 
If in this locking request I make there are a lot of `insert` and `update` operations, should the isolation level be `REPEATABLE READ`? 
Is there any way to debug/process that kind of situations? 
Is there any mechanism to timeout that locks so app can be easily/automatically released and not blocking further requests?

Side question (since I'm not looking for a tool directly): are there any tools to monitor and spot that kind of situations? (I was hoping to use Munin.)

I am using nodejs 4.2.1 with express 4.13.3, sequelize 3.19.3 as Postgres 9.4.1 ORM.

Comment: Did you check pg_stat_activity and pg_locks? What kind of locks do you see? And what about the postgres logfiles? Do you see deadlocks?

Comment: @FrankHeikens, I've already checked `pg_stat_activity` and didn't see anything suspicious, however maybe I don't know how to check it correctly. When it comes to types of locks and log files viewing I've already mentioned it in my question. Does `GRANTED = true` mean that there are no deadlocks? How can I verify it correctly?

Comment: @FrankHeikens About comments, I can found also this: `ERROR:  could not serialize access due to concurrent update` which I didn't see before. When I kill the app while it's stuck, in logs appears `LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction` several times.

Comment: Hard to tell what the problem is without code and requirements, but it's a known issue: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/transaction-iso.html#XACT-REPEATABLE-READ Root cause: A repeatable read transaction cannot modify or lock rows changed by other transactions after the repeatable read transaction began.

Comment: @kasiacode, did you eventually find a fix for this? I'm having a similar issue and I am currently at a dead end.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to PostgreSQL transaction locks hell :)

You can spend a lot of time trying to figure out where exactly the lock happens and why. But there is a very little chance that it will help you in resolving the situation.

The general recipe for solving this kind of situations is as follows:

- Keep your transactions size to the bare minimum required by the business logic of your application. For example, avoid same-type inserts or updates, replacing them with multi-row analogues, because query IO is expensive
- Do not use transactions while executing only a single query that modifies data, i.e. avoid unnecessary transactions.
- Implement error handling that can determine a transaction lock and provide a repeated attempt at executing the transaction. Logging such repeats will help you understand weak spots of your system and how to redesign it better.

Even in a well-engineered system the last step often becomes a necessity, don't let it scare you ;)

Comment: Hell? Why? Transactions can help you, they should help you. But you do need a good design.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't help me much in the current situation. I was always thinking as @FrankHeikens that transactions helps a lot. Do you mean that only Postgres' transactions are hell or generally? Anyway it would be great to read more about how wisely design transactions in the app.

Comment: @kasiacode I meant the transaction locks only (corrected my answer).

Comment: I also really need a guide on how to design transactions with postgresql. The ones I find are on a way to high level.

Comment: @vitaly-t Thanks for your answer, it was quite helpful to me and my issue was adding to many unnecessary transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar situation where I started 5 parallell transactions requesting the same update lock, and the first one also continued with work that required more postgres calls. The entire system deadlocks, and the first transaction is listed as idle in transaction in pg_stat_activity and granted access to all locks it has requested in pg_locks.

What I think is happening;

The first transaction got the lock granted, and then finished the query. After this it drops its connection to postgres.

The following 4 transactions open a connection each and blocks on the lock, that is held by the first transaction.

Since they are blocked, the first transaction gets to execute, when it tries to connect to postgres to make a query, it gets deadlocked, because sequiezlize has run out of connections.

When I changed my sequiezlize initialisation and added more connections to the pool, default being 5, the deadlock disappears.

I am not sure who is using the 5'th connection, or if the default happens to be 4 and not 5, for some reason, but still seem to tick all the boxes.

Another solution is to use the NOWAIT option in postgres, so a transaction abort when asking for a lock and not getting it, depending on your usecase.

Hope it helps if someone else gets encounters the same issue.